# WindowsAzure: Add directory to %path% environment variable when a webrole starts

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-roles

I want to add a directory name to the %PATH% environment variable when my webrole starts, either by using a startup task (prefered) or the OnStart method of the C# RoleEntryPoint class.

Unfortunately, I had no luck finding an example.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Marius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A startup task that sets the environment variable when it runs, something like this should work 'Setting environment variables in Windows Azure'

http://nicoploner.blogspot.com.au/2011/11/setting-environment-variables-in.html